# How to define a variable contained in a tuple?

Tags: haskell, happstack

Every time I tried to run this code, the compiler returns a 'not in scope' error for the variables `redirectUrlGraphEmail`, `redirectUrlGraphPost`, `aboutContents`, and `staticDir`:

```
routes :: [ (String, ServerPart Response)]
routes = [
("graph-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail $ toResponse ""),
("post-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphPost $ toResponse ""),               
("about", aboutResponse aboutContents),
("static", serveDirectory DisableBrowsing [] staticDir)]
```

These variables are declared by:

```
staticDir <- getStaticDir
redirectUrlGraphEmail <- retrieveAuthURL testUrl
redirectUrlGraphPost <- retrieveAuthURL testPostUrl
aboutContents <- LazyIO.readFile $ markdownPath ++ "README.md"
privacyContents <- LazyIO.readFile $ markdownPath ++ "PRIVACY.md"
```

but I am not sure where should I add these lines into the module. Any help here?

Comment: Can you show us a full example in one file?  It seems like you are expecting the variables to be global or some such.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know happstack but it seems that your variables `redirectUrlGraphEmail` etc. are defined in your main (or in some monad at least), right? And then you want to define `route` as a separate function in your module.

The thing is, the variables you define (that you bind with `<-` to be precise) in your `main` are local to your `main`, so the rest of your program doesn't have access to them (which is why the compiler tells you they're not in scope when you try to use them in `routes`). If you want to make use of them, you need to define `routes` as a function taking them as parameters, so in your case:

```
routes redirectUrlGraphEmail redirectUrlGraphPost = [
 ("graph-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail $ toResponse ""),
 ("post-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphPost $ toResponse ""),               
 ("about", aboutResponse aboutContents),
 ("static", serveDirectory DisableBrowsing [] staticDir)]
```

And then from your `main` call `routes` with the variables you've bind. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks for your explanation! Another question here is in the main module, the way I call `routes` is `(map (\ (a, b) -> dir a b) $ routes)` ,which maps the function `dir` to each tuple in `routes`. And `dir` takes in two elements in the tuple both as variables. How can I combine this with calling `routes` in main with variables that I've bind?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can simply apply `routes` to its arguments, so you can just write `map (\(a,b) -> dir a b) $ routes redirectUrlGraphEmail redirectUrlGraphPost…`.
Note that in your original formulation, you didn't need the `$`, writing `map (\(a,b) -> dir a b) routes` would have been fine ;)

Comment: I see! Then do I need to add those variables in my routes function?          like                                                                                                           `routes :: [ (String, ServerPart Response)]
routes staticDir redirectUrlGraphEmail redirectUrlGraphPost aboutContents privacyContents = [
("graph-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphEmail $ toResponse ""),
("post-fb", seeOther redirectUrlGraphPost $ toResponse ""),               
("about", aboutResponse aboutContents),
("static", serveDirectory DisableBrowsing [] staticDir)]`